# Are there any video lectures that teach Weinberg's QFT books?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I am reading Weinberg's QFT books. I wonder is there any course can help me with it.

Comment: This Q is specifically about Weinberg. I can't see an answer in the duplicate